# Can someone explain this line of code in the missing django-allauth tutorial?

Tags: django, django-models, django-allauth

I'm doing the django-allauth tutorial here: http://www.sarahhagstrom.com/2013/09/the-missing-django-allauth-tutorial/

I have difficult understanding what this line means. I think the purpose is to create a UserProfile when a User is created, but I don't understand how it achieves that.

```
User.profile = property(lambda u: UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])
```

Comment: What django version you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line monkey patches the `User` class in order to add a profile instance property.

If we *could* change `User`, we'd add the following inside the `User` class (it's the same albeit instead of `u` you use `self` for the parameter):

```
@property
def profile(self):
  UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=self)[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Django > 1.5 you can have [Custom User Model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/#auth-custom-user) instead of writing profile model for user, also check [instructions](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced.html#custom-user-models) related with allauth for using custom user model. If you insist to use profile model then there are much better way of creating the user profile when the user has signed up. For example if you have `ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION="mandatory"` then you should create the user profile when the user has successfully verified his/her email by writing the handler for [allauth.account.signals.email_confirmed](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/signals.html) signal. Else if email verification is not required then you have two options, either create the user profile by writing handler for [allauth.account.signals.user_signed_up](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/signals.html) signal or create it using the `signup` method of your custom signup form:

```
class SignupFormExtra(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(SignupFormExtra, self).__init__(*args, **kw)

    def signup(self, request, user):
        UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        return user
```

And tell allauth to use this signup form as a base class:

```
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'myproject.myappp.forms.SignupFormExtra'
```

And tell django to use site specific profile model (django < 1.5):

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = "myapp.UserProfile"
```

P.S The blog article is very old and since then there is much change in the `allauth`. You should follow the official [documentation](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) for package also.